# Android Dagger2 and Butterknife conflict

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, butterknife

I learn how to use dagger2 and Butterknife in my android project, everything is work fine until I inject the view with Butterknife BindView annotation, it display error like this ;

Error:(5, 57) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerNetComponent

this is my DaggerNetComponent code :

```
public class App extends Application {

private NetComponent mNetComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(this)).netModule(new NetModule("http://example.com/"))
            .build();
}

public NetComponent getNetComponent()
{
    return mNetComponent;
}
```

}

and this is how I inject my view with butterknife :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainScreenContact.View {

@BindView(R.id.listContact)
ListView listView;

ArrayList<CharSequence> list;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

@Inject
MainScreenPresenter mainPresenter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

if I remove the BindView annotation and ButterKnife bind on this class, then it works fine, but if I use it, the error will appear.

this is my Gradle.app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'


android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project.echo.contactmanagement"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner      "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'

//Retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
//OkHttp
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.7.0'

//Gson
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'

//RxJava
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.2'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

//Dagger
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

//butterknife
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
}
```

Please help me, any answer will be appreciate...

Thank you..

Comment: If your ButterKnife annotation processing fails, your Dagger can fail as well. Check that `R.id.listContact` points to a instance of `ListView and try cleaning and rebuilding. Also, check for any other compile time errors.

Comment: My ButterKnife annotation doesn't fail and R.id.listContact is pointed to ListView. I have try to clean and rebuilding the code, but the error still showin, the error will go away if I remove the ButterKnife annotation

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Dagger 2 and the latest version of ButterKnife? Edit your post to include `build.gradle` at the very least. Even better, create the minimum project that replicates the issue - we have been using those two libraries together in a project for some time with no issues like this.

Comment: Hello @DavidRawson , I have edited my question with my gradle.app. Please take a look and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using the same annotation plugin for both dependencies:

```
// Butter Knife
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
// Dagger 2
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

Came up with this fix after reading the following issue:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/803

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution, but I dont think this is the perfect one. I change the butterknife version from 8.1.0 to 8.0.1 and then everything works fine. I change it in my gradle.app

```
//butterknife
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
```

Comment: What about changing dagger version to 2.8?

Answer (score 0):

When using `apt` scope, you need to add the following `packagingOptions` to `android {` in your build.gradle:

```
android {
    // ...
    packagingOptions {
        // Exclude file to avoid
        // Error: Duplicate files during packaging of APK
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'  // <-- that one
    }
}
```

And I also think you should only apply `android-apt` only once.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
//apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

---

But another possibility is that you are trying to bind a view that doesn't exist in the layout, and so ButterKnife fails at compile time now.

Comment: I have try this, but doesnt works, still get the error.

Comment: Then check your compilation error messages beyond "dagger component doesn't exist", it ought to be there somewhere